# Error importing objects: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `payments` directory with two files: `constants.js` and `controller.js`

`constants.js`:

```
export const STRIPE_CONSTANTS = {
  USD: 'usd',
  SKU: 'sku',
};

export const SKU_CONSTANTS = {
  first_sku: 'sku_abc123',
};
```

and in my `controller.js`, I import, but get an error:

`import { STRIPE_CONSTANTS, SKU_CONSTANTS } from './constants';`

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { STRIPE_CONSTANTS, SKU_CONSTANTS } from './constants';
>                                                                        ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are executing the code using node runtime which has not implemented the `ES modules` yet. ( This would run on browsers though if you are using a transpiler first to convert from ES6 to ES5)

You need to use `require` to import the module and `exports` to export them.

`ES modules` been implemented in node `8.5.0` and later but the caveat is that the file name should end with `.mjs` instead so that they don't break existing code.

**constants.js**

```
const STRIPE_CONSTANTS = {
  USD: 'usd',
  SKU: 'sku',
};

const SKU_CONSTANTS = {
  first_sku: 'sku_abc123',
};

exports.STRIPE_CONSTANTS = STRIPE_CONSTANTS;
exports.SKU_CONSTANTS = SKU_CONSTANTS;

// If you want to export it as an object instead of that you 
// can use destructing when importing them you can use `module.exports`
// instead

module.exports = {
   STRIPE_CONSTANTS,
   SKU_CONSTANTS
}
```

**controller.js**

```
const constants = require('./constants');

const STRIPE_CONSTANTS = constants.STRIPE_CONSTANTS;
const SKU_CONSTANTS = constants.SKU_CONSTANTS;

// If constants was exported as an object using `module.exports`
// you can use destructing instead

const { STRIPE_CONSTANTS, SKU_CONSTANTS } = require('./constants');
```

Comment: Or implement babel in your node app with `@babel/register`.

Comment: Sure. That would be one more way